# Canon EDSDK MemoryStream Image

Tags: c#, dll, unmanaged, edsdk

I've been fighting with the Canon EDSDK for a while now.  I can successfully get the library to save a file directly to disk, however, I cannot get a hold of the image byte[] in memory.  Whenever I attempt to Marshal.Copy() the EDSDK Stream to byte[], I always get the following error:

*AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.*

Below is one of the variations of code that I've used to try and get the stream:

```
        private uint downloadImage(IntPtr directoryItem)
        {
            uint err = EDSDK.EDS_ERR_OK;
            IntPtr stream = IntPtr.Zero;

            // Get information of the directory item.
            EDSDK.EdsDirectoryItemInfo dirItemInfo;
            err = EDSDK.EdsGetDirectoryItemInfo(directoryItem, out dirItemInfo);

            // Create a file stream for receiving image.
            if (err == EDSDK.EDS_ERR_OK)
            {
                err = EDSDK.EdsCreateMemoryStream(dirItemInfo.Size, out stream);
            }

            //  Fill the stream with the resulting image
            if (err == EDSDK.EDS_ERR_OK)
            {
                err = EDSDK.EdsDownload(directoryItem, dirItemInfo.Size, stream);
            }

            //  Copy the stream to a byte[] and 
            if (err == EDSDK.EDS_ERR_OK)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[dirItemInfo.Size];

                GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                // The following line is where it blows up...
                Marshal.Copy(stream, buffer, 0, (int)dirItemInfo.Size);

                // ... Image manipulation, show user, whatever
            }

            return err;
        }
```

Breakpoints reveal (Through the EdsDirectoryItemInfo object) that the image is indeed there, I just don't know why I'd be getting the exception that I am.  I have been toying with the idea of accepting defeat and just read the resultant image from disk that it so readily writes via the CreateFileStream method, but I really ought to just be able to manipulate the image in memory.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: I see this behavior in both versions 2.5 and 2.6.

Comment: Would you mind posting your code (somewhere) to download the picture you just took to disk? I can't even get that far. Specifically, I cannot get it to call my object event handler function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just googled for `EdsCreateMemoryStream` and [found a sample](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=3&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffiledb.experts-exchange.com%2Fincoming%2F2008%2F10_w44%2F72271%2Ftest.txt&ei=o2NQSsCpJKLMjAetqbhE&usg=AFQjCNEpLP7pv6rF9-Uv99SMHq3NwsBvgA&sig2=fhFU1F44uhVecWVrrzLsXA) in which there's another call to get the pointer from the "memory stream".

```
IntPtr pointerToBytes;
EDSDKLib.EDSDK.EdsGetPointer(stream, out pointerToBytes);
```

You can then use `pointerToBytes` as the source to read from in `Marshal.Copy`.

So I'd guess that what you're currently doing is attempting to copy some large number of bytes starting from the address of some small control structure pointed to by `stream`, and hence you're reading past the end of that structure.

**Edit:** By the way, you're code looks as if someone's told you that you should only have one return statement! That's old advice relating to languages like Fortran and C; it doesn't make sense in modern languages. Your code would be clearer (at least in this case) if you immediately returned the error code every time you got a failure:

```
if ((err = EDSDK.EdsBlahBlah(...)) != EDSDK.EDS_ERR_OK)
    return err;
```

(Better yet, throw a specific exception class containing the error code and a string explaining what you were trying to do.)

Comment: This particular method is just a wrapper method (a test one at that) for the EDSDK, so duelly noted. I'll give the pointer read a try when I get home.

Answer (score 5):

I realize that this is an old post, but this is a complete C# snippet for downloading from a memory stream. It may be useful for someone else. The camera needs to be set to EDSDK.EdsSaveTo.Host or EDSDK.EdsSaveTo.Both

```
        uint error = EDSDK.EDS_ERR_OK;
        IntPtr stream = IntPtr.Zero;

        EDSDK.EdsDirectoryItemInfo directoryItemInfo;

        error = EDSDK.EdsGetDirectoryItemInfo(this.DirectoryItem, out directoryItemInfo);

        //create a file stream to accept the image
        if (error == EDSDK.EDS_ERR_OK)
        {
            error = EDSDK.EdsCreateMemoryStream(directoryItemInfo.Size, out stream);
        }


        //down load image
        if (error == EDSDK.EDS_ERR_OK)
        {
            error = EDSDK.EdsDownload(this.DirectoryItem, directoryItemInfo.Size, stream);
        }

        //complete download
        if (error == EDSDK.EDS_ERR_OK)
        {
            error = EDSDK.EdsDownloadComplete(this.DirectoryItem);
        }


        //convert to memory stream
        IntPtr pointer; //pointer to image stream
        EDSDK.EdsGetPointer(stream, out pointer);

        uint length = 0;
        EDSDK.EdsGetLength(stream, out length);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[length];

        //Move from unmanaged to managed code.
        Marshal.Copy(pointer, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes);
        Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream);

        if (pointer != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            EDSDK.EdsRelease(pointer);
            pointer = IntPtr.Zero;
        }


        if (this.DirectoryItem != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            EDSDK.EdsRelease(this.DirectoryItem);
            this.DirectoryItem = IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        if (stream != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            EDSDK.EdsRelease(stream);
            stream = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
```